# Can't display images using shuffle function

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and I am trying to use shuffle function to display random images from array on my site. It's not working and I don't know what is the mistake. It shows only one picture or none at all. My code is below.

```
<?php
$pic= array('1.jpg','2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg','5.jpg');
shuffle($pic);

?>
```

// the beginning

```
<?php
    for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
    echo "<li> <img src=\""?><?php echo base_url();?><?php echo"images/slike_sajt/$pic[$i]\" width=\"60\" height=\"50\"></li>";
                ?>
```

//code in the body part

Answer (score 0):

You have image concatenation issues, Try this,

```
$pic= array('1.jpg','2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg','5.jpg');
shuffle($pic);
 foreach($pic as $picture){
     $image = base_url()."images/slike_sajt/".$picture;
     echo "<li> <img src='$image'  width='60' height='50'></li>";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
    for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
    {
      echo "<li><img src='".base_url("images/slike_sajt/".$pic[$i])."' width='60' height= '50'></li>";
    }
?>
```